# What is an anti-siphon trap?

Tags: plumbing, terminology

I have seen traps by the same manufacturer with some designated as **non-siphon** and others as **anti-siphon**.  What do those terms mean in a domestic waste plumbing context?

Answer (score 1):

A siphon can be used to empty a bucket without a pump from one level to a lower level using a pipe.

However,in some situations the siphon is an unwanted behavior like in a toilet as water needs to stay in the bend to act as an airlock to prevent noxious gases coming up from the sewer pipes. So designs to prevent the siphon are necessary.

Comment: Yes, but is there any difference between the design/functionality of anti-siphon vs non-siphon?

Comment: @mrblint Yes. Anti-siphon prevents siphons. Non-siphon doesn't. This feature needs to be designed so they also look slightly different. Are you asking about exactly how they're different? You can take a look [here](http://www.hkengineer.org.hk/issue/vol36-jun2008/feature_story/?id=13088) for examples of both properly and badly installed p-traps.

Comment: @Nelson, I think you're wrong about the terms. "anti" and "non" are essentially equivalent. It's a marketing choice, not a function distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the terms are interchangeable. If you Google (or DuckDuckGo in my case): ***non-siphon plumbing***, you get anti-siphon results.

Comment: This doesn't answer crux  of the question, which wasn't just comparing the terms but seeking to define them (as potential synonyms).